# How to make JButton borderless in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Im trying to improve the Java GUI of my project in Netbeans, below is the picture of my project in Netbeans's design palette , the 4 texts are actually JButtons which I have set the Border to false to improve the design.

[image]

However in the picture below, you can see the result is quite different from what it should look like and the borders are still there even when I set it as false, I do not know how to get it to look like the picture on top, Ive provided the code for this below for your reference.[image]

Code here: (as you can see I already setBorderPainted(false) which I thought will do the trick but no)

```
HomeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

HomeButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));

HomeButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N

HomeButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

HomeButton.setText("Home");

HomeButton.setBorderPainted(false);

HomeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        HomeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

If you know how to get the result of my code to look like the first image please do update me. Thank you.

Comment: Create a vertical JToolBar and add your buttons to it.  They will be borderless by default.

Comment: Have you tried [`HomeButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled-boolean-) along with `setBorderPainted(false)`?

Comment: I just tried and its working, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
HomeButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

along with:

```
HomeButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

... in which case I think setting the background color is not needed, but I am not sure.